# launch a Windows application from a web browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, exe, activex, external

I'm trying to launch a Windows application from a web browser, just like the VMWare console (VMRC) from a vCenter web interface, or the Zoom binary from a simple html link.

I understand Java applets, NAPI protocol and ActiveX are considered deprecated, so what is the best method please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register as [a protocol handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in the registry.

To handle `foo://something` URLs for example, the .reg file would look something like

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\foo]
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\foo\shell\open\command] 
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MyApp\\MyApp.exe\" \"%1\""
```

If your app is not already installed on the system you might want to look at [ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learn-more-co-di) instead.

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought :-).